# What is a "Roaming MAC address" and why is it not secure?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to setup a web-based application that will be accessed via Wifi connection on a tablet by users.

The response I've received from the tech team responsible for connecting this up is that "they have roaming MAC addresses" and so they cannot be connected to a secure network.

As I understand it a MAC address is a hardware address... every device capable of a network connection has one. So what makes it roaming and why does this make it insecure? Are there any options that could be suggested?

Comment: There's something very wrong about a "secure network" relying on MAC addresses at all...

Comment: @grawity OP did say that the network can not be secure because they're relying on MAC addresses. `"they have roaming MAC addresses" and so they cannot be connected to a secure network.`

Comment: @dsstorefile1 the application doesn't, but the objective was to simply get these tablets connecting via Wifi to a LAN and "no, we can't because..." was the response. They've made it sound like some unsolvable problem.

Comment: The bigger question is where is this web application located? Is it an internal site? The only reason these tablets would have trouble on any network is if the website is meant to only be accessed by very specific devices. So maybe the problem is the idea of limiting this site to very specific devices when there are certainly other ways to secure the site.

Comment: @Appleoddity on server accessible via VPN connection usually from a laptop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent tracking users between different networks by their MAC address, many mobile devices use a different MAC address for each network that they connect to. These are called roaming MAC addresses. However, they annoy security people, who have (often perfectly valid) reasons for wanting to be able to track users across different networks. It also makes it impossible to whitelist a device in advance, since you don’t know what MAC address it will use.

Comment: I see... how would someone find tablets or other "mobile" devices that don't have roaming mac addresses? what am I looking for on a spec?

Comment: I would get a Windows tablet — you can turn off the randomisation in Windows. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027925/windows-how-and-why-to-use-random-hardware-addresses

Comment: or Android 7 and lower or 9 and higher. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization